# How to obtain the centroid of cells/elements in VTK?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vtk, meshio

I know how to get the coordinates of the points in an unstructured grid from this post: [vtk to matplotlib using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138112/vtk-to-matplotlib-using-numpy)

However, I am trying to find a function that takes the unstructured VTK grid and returns the coordinates of the "centers" of the cells/elements. In particular, I'm working with a cylinder composed of quad elements. Here's the code I have so far:

```
from srlife import writers #library that helps make vtk grid
import numpy as np
import vtk 
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

vtkTube1 = writers.VTKWriter(tube1, 'tube1.vtk')
grid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
for x,y,z in zip(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten()):
        points.InsertNextPoint(x,y,z)
grid.SetPoints(points)
vtkTube1._set_grid(grid)

getCellLocations = vtk_to_numpy(grid.GetCellLocationsArray()) #this just returns 1D array of integers that I don't know what to do with
```

I tried looking into meshio and griddata from scipy.interpolate but the documentation wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`GetCellLocationsArray` does not return geometrical information (see [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkUnstructuredGrid.html#ac4208186c8e221301f96b475325dd14e)) but the indices of the beginning of each cell in the cell array returned by `GetCells`

You can try the [vtkCellCenters](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellCenters.html#details) filter.

Note: doc is C++ but python API is really similar.